# region monitoring only works on second launch

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

(somebody asks a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466104/cllocationmanager-only-monitors-regions-the-first-time-the-app-is-run-after-inst) but the situation - or at least the info I provide - are different in my case)

I am using the following code to check whether the user is already located within a region

```
var m_location_manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        // .. 
        m_location_manager.delegate = self
        m_location_manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        m_location_manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        m_location_manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let region = CLCircularRegion( ... ) 
        m_location_manager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    }

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
    m_location_manager.requestStateForRegion(region)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let circular_region = region as! CLCircularRegion
    if circular_region.containsCoordinate((m_location_manager.location?.coordinate)!) {
        // do something .. 
    }
}
```

I'm testing in on the simulator currently (Xcode 7.3). The code works fine but when I reset the simulator and start it again, the very first time it won't work. This is when I first get asked if I want to give my app the necessary permissions and, it seems to me, that even if I accept, permissions are not granted until the next time the application starts. This piece of code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
            print(true)
        } else {
            print(false)
        }
    }
```

When run on a 'fresh' simulator session I first get `false` and once I hit the 'allow' on the alert window asking for permission I do get `true`. (Note that even if I move the code snippet for the region monitoring inside the `true` clause, nothing happens.) All subsequent times I get `true` directly and region monitoring works as expected.

any ideas?